# Can I use ruby's .map but also pass in an argument?

Tags: ruby

I have an array of integers, floats, and booleans. I want to convert all the elements to floats.

If it were only integers and floats, I could do something like:

```
my_array.map(&:to_f)
```

However, the booleans complicate this.

I can write a function like this:

```
def my_object_to_float(var)
    if(var.is_a?(Integer))
       return var.to_f
    elsif(var.is_a?(Float))
        return var
    else
        return var ? 1.0 : 0.0
    end
end
```

But is there any way to call this function from map like so:

```
my_array.map(&:my_object_to_float)
```

Comment: You might consider using a `respond_to?(:to_f)` check instead of explicit class tests. That should take care of `Rational`, `Bignum`, ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

```
> my_array.map(&method(:my_object_to_float))
```

And it can be cleaner, e.g.,

```
def object_to_float(var)
  if var.is_a?(Integer)
   var.to_f
  elsif var.is_a?(Float)
    var
  else
    var ? 1.0 : 0.0
  end
end

> a = [1, 2.0, true, false]
> puts a.map(&method(:object_to_float))
1.0
2.0
1.0
0.0
```

You could also just check to see if the object responds to `to_f` and use whatever is already defined, and use truthiness for the remaining types that don't, e.g.,

```
def object_to_float(obj)
  obj.respond_to?(:to_f) ? obj.to_f : obj ? 1.0 : 0.0
end
```

Of course, nested ternaries are bad.

Comment: Awesome thanks. I'll go this route and combine it with respond_to?(:to_f)

Comment: Why do you need to define a method just for that? You can simply put that in a block passed to `map`.

Comment: @sawa You don't, but OP has one. I'd tend towards a method because it's independently testable, but am largely ambivalent.

Comment: A lambda might be an alternative if `object_to_float` is only needed in one place: `object_to_float = ->(var) { ... }; a.map(&object_to_float)`.

Answer (score 3):

Your code could be a bit cleaner with a `case` statement and a `lambda`:

```
object_to_float = lambda { |x|
  case x
  when Float then x
  when Numeric then x.to_f
  when true then 1.0
  else 0.0
  end
}

p [1, 2, true, false, nil, 3.0].map(&object_to_float)
# [1.0, 2.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.0]
```

Comment: I think I like the case better; more pattern-matchy.

Answer (score 0):

```
def true.to_f; 1.0 end
def false.to_f; 0.0 end

my_array.map(&:to_f)
```

Comment: But we all know monkey-patching is bad ;) In this case I have no strong objection, but it's still sketchy.

Comment: I wouldn't do such thing like this in the first place.

Comment: Yep; a mixed list like this usually means something else is wrong higher up.

Comment: The tensorflow model I'm using expects an array of floats.  It would be nice if it could just take bools and ints as well, but sadly the ruby tensorflow library is not very flexible.

Comment: And @DaveNewton The list is mixed because I'm actually taking the values from a hash which define the features which go into the neural network.  Definitely not something you'd run into in a normal use case.